# Shape incoming traffic using tc (and IFB?) on a NAT ed interface

Tags: wireless, networking, internet-connection, ethernet

I have an Ubuntu machine acting as a router/Stateful Firewall/NAT for my internet connection. It has a couple of ethernet ports and a wireless network for my home network (eth5, eth7, eth10 and wlan1). It is connected with a DSL modem in bridged mode giving it a connection to the internet called ppp0. I currently use tc and a simple rate limit (TBF, IIRC) to shape the outgoing traffic (which works great -- no matter how much is uploading, my connection does not increase latency because of it, which is the goal).

What I would like to do is use tc to limit and prioritize my incoming traffic. I know you can't do this without setting a a fake device, using IMQ or IFB. (I believe IFB is the new, "right" way to do it.)

So, how do I set up IFB so I can I set up IFB so I can set up a simple TBF limit  for now (and later set up bandwidth allocations, like TCP ack packets get a certain guaranteed amount of bandwidth)?

Comment: I really like the question, but I think it might be a better fit on UL instead of AU.  UL tends to field more server/appliance/technical questions, in my opinion, where AU tends to field more 'getting my desktop running properly' questions.  I could be mistaken though.  If you post it on UL instead, definitely delete the question here when you do.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to move it there and not to post another similar question? In my opinion this question might also be good at serverfault.com. There were several questions of this kind answered.

Comment: I agree on serverfault being another possible.  I think a post and delete sidesteps dumping work on moderators, so I'm all for it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good read. It involves installing shorewall though.

http://www.shorewall.net/traffic_shaping.htm#IFB